# Polynomial over field F

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Reading white papers on QSP, I stumbled upon

"
A QSP over a field F with polynomials $$
u_{0}, ... u_{m},w_{0}, ... ,w_{m}
$$ over this field F. 
"

My question is, what is the constraint placed over the polynomials to say that they are "polynomials over a field F"? Do they have a certain degree? Are their coefficients limited to numbers in a set? 
I've been looking online but most resources assume this notion of "over a field F", this must be something very trivial but I would love to know what this means formally before making any assumptions.

Comment: never heard of QSP   So you should probably say wht it stands for and the title of one or more specific articlesw, books

Comment: @WillJagy would this have any meaning without the QSP? If it was only mentioned that u0, ..., um, w0, ..., wm were polynomials over field F, would this have any meaning on its own?

Comment: You really have not given us enough context. At first, I thought that the $u_i$ and the $w_i$ were variables, but on puzzling over your snippet — it’s not even a sentence — I think that maybe these $2m$ things are polynomials themselves, and in that case, one would expect that the author should have made clear what the variables are. Maybe they’re all polynomials in the same one variable? Tell us more, inquiring minds would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial over a field (or ring) $F$ is just a polynomial whose coefficients are elements of $F$.

Comment: But what belongs to F? If the text is not defining what belongs in F, are there default members of this set?

Comment: $F$ is just a variable.  Lacking any additional context, all you know about it is that it refers to a field.  In context, it is possible that $F$ is given a specific definition, but you have not provided such context.